# A* (A-Star) Algorithm Help

Tags: c#, xna, path-finding, a-star

Well, this is my updated code. It doesn't slow down, but no path appears.

```
public static IntPosition[] GetPath(BlockType[,] blocks, IntPosition start, IntPosition end, int threshhold)
    {
        List<Node> MapNodes = new List<Node>();
        MapNodes.Add(new Node() { Position = start });

        bool[,] explored = new bool[blocks.GetLength(0), blocks.GetLength(1)];

        explored[start.X, start.Y] = true;

        int? endNode = null;

        int index = 0;
        while (endNode == null && index < threshhold)
        {
            List<Node> addNodes = new List<Node>();


            foreach (Node n in MapNodes)
            {
                //left
                if (n.Position.X - 1 >= 0)
                    if (explored[n.Position.X - 1, n.Position.Y] == false)
                        if (blocks[n.Position.X - 1, n.Position.Y] == BlockType.Open)
                        {
                            int i = addNodes.Count;
                            addNodes.Add(new Node() { Position = new IntPosition(n.Position.X - 1, n.Position.Y), ParentNode = n });

                            explored[n.Position.X - 1, n.Position.Y] = true;

                            if (addNodes[i].Position == end)
                                endNode = i;
                        }

                //right
                if (n.Position.X + 1 <= blocks.GetLength(0) - 1)
                    if (explored[n.Position.X + 1, n.Position.Y] == false)
                        if (blocks[n.Position.X + 1, n.Position.Y] == BlockType.Open)
                        {
                            int i = addNodes.Count;
                            addNodes.Add(new Node() { Position = new IntPosition(n.Position.X + 1, n.Position.Y), ParentNode = n });

                            explored[n.Position.X + 1, n.Position.Y] = true;

                            if (addNodes[i].Position == end)
                                endNode = i;
                        }

                //up
                if (n.Position.Y - 1 >= 0)
                    if (explored[n.Position.X, n.Position.Y - 1] == false)
                        if (blocks[n.Position.X, n.Position.Y - 1] == BlockType.Open)
                        {
                            int i = addNodes.Count;
                            addNodes.Add(new Node() { Position = new IntPosition(n.Position.X, n.Position.Y - 1), ParentNode = n });

                            explored[n.Position.X, n.Position.Y - 1] = true;

                            if (addNodes[i].Position == end)
                                endNode = i;
                        }

                //down
                if (n.Position.Y + 1 <= blocks.GetLength(1))
                    if (explored[n.Position.X, n.Position.Y + 1] == false)
                        if (blocks[n.Position.X, n.Position.Y + 1] == BlockType.Open)
                        {
                            int i = addNodes.Count;
                            addNodes.Add(new Node() { Position = new IntPosition(n.Position.X, n.Position.Y + 1), ParentNode = n });

                            explored[n.Position.X, n.Position.Y + 1] = true;

                            if (addNodes[i].Position == end)
                                endNode = i;
                        }
            }

            MapNodes.AddRange(addNodes);

            index++;
        }

        if (endNode == null)
            return new IntPosition[] { };
        else
        {
            List<IntPosition> path = new List<IntPosition>();

            path.Add(end);

            Node CurrentNode = (MapNodes[(int)endNode].ParentNode);
            bool endReached = false;

            while (endReached == false)
            {
                path.Add(CurrentNode.Position);

                if (CurrentNode.Position == start)
                    endReached = true;
                else
                    CurrentNode = CurrentNode.ParentNode;
            }


            path.Reverse();
            return path.ToArray();
        }
    }



public class IntPosition
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public IntPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public IntPosition() { X = 0; Y = 0; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((IntPosition)obj).X == X && ((IntPosition)obj).Y == Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would refer to this method as A* for future reference, because I wasn't sure what you meant by "A Star" at first. I believe A* is a more common way to see this written out.

Comment: Do the objects of type `IntPosition` compare with `==` on _value_ or on _reference_? `if (addNodes[i].Position == end)` would never match if `==` compares for reference equality, but could match if `==` compares for value equality.

Comment: Check the end of my question.

Comment: I've posted my updated code, it doesn't slow down, but it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the code. Firstly, your X + 1 and Y + 1 checks have the comparison the wrong way around (greater-than instead of less-than). I suspect that's what causing the algorithm to fail.

Secondly, while I'm not familiar with the algorithm, I suspect you need to do something to ensure that nodes you've already check are not checked again in subsequent iterations. Also, you need to make sure you don't add nodes to `MapNodes` that are already present. The combination of these is likely to be the cause of the slowness you're seeing, because it will result in exponential growth of `MapNodes` with many redundant nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Next to what Chris mentions, there's something else wrong with your usage of `MapNodes`. It needs to be sorted, and contain all members, including all nodes you put on the list `addNodes`. Caching all nodes which need to be added to `MapNodes` is not a valid A* implementation. When you add a node to `addNodes`, it should actually be added to `MapNodes` and `MapNodes` should then be sorted by F, which is a number associated with a node, which is the sum of the total cost from the startnode to that node and the value of a heuristic function evaluated for that node. There are multiple descriptions of heuristic functions on the internet, I suggest you try to read about that.

And btw, where's the heuristic in your code? An A* algorithm is just a slow Dijkstra algorithm without a heuristic. I'm afraid what you've implemented resembles Dijkstra more that A*.

And to answer your actual question: the algorithm probably doesn't yield a path because there are bugs, preventing the search algorithm from actually reaching the destination node.